# How to pass parameter to modal in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, svelte

Hello I need your help because I use modal in my svelte app but I need to pass parameter to the modal component to choose what I wrote inside of it. But in the open() function of Modal we just need to give the component we imported so I don't know how to pass the parameter.

Here some code I have :

```
import { getContext } from 'svelte';
import ModalContent from './ModalContent.svelte';

export let title;

const { open } = getContext('simple-modal');
  
    const showModal = () => {
      open(ModalContent);
    };
```

But I would like something like this :

```
import { getContext } from 'svelte';
import ModalContent from './ModalContent.svelte';

export let title;

const { open } = getContext('simple-modal');
  
    const showModal = () => {
      open(<ModalContent texte={title} />);
    };
```

Comment: What does your `open` function do? Depending on that you can create the modal with `const modal = new ModalContent({target: document.body, props: {text: title}})` and then use `open(modal)`. The relevant part of the documentation would be https://svelte.dev/docs#Client-side_component_API

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the [svelte-simple-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-simple-modal) component. In that case, you'll want to pass the props as an object to the second argument of the `open()` function.

```js
import { getContext } from 'svelte';
import ModalContent from './ModalContent.svelte';

export let title;

const { open } = getContext('simple-modal');
  
const showModal = () => {
  open(ModalContent, {texte: title});
};
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flekschas/svelte-simple-modal#context-api) for more information.